# Change hover text of a plotly express treemap

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I want to show in a treemap just the label and value of each item, not parent or ID. I have defined it with plotly express. No matter how much I have tinkered with it, I haven’t been able to restrict hover text to the fields I need. Check the code and capture

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.treemap(dfconcepto, path=['type','name'], 
                 values = 'count',
                 width=900, height=900,
                 hover_data = ['count'],
)

fig.show()
```

[image: image image 1117×957 44.9 KB]
I also have tried to create it with non-express treemap. Hovertext is what I want, but then a treemap with two levels is rendered asymmetric.

[image]

What I want is something like the hovertext of non-express treemap, but balanced and symmetric as in express treemap

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mind to share `dfconcepto` so we can reproduce it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jlchulilla/3b4e40f68ba73b5dbcb661a1d861f308

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me you should overwrite your hover template

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jlchulilla/3b4e40f68ba73b5dbcb661a1d861f308/raw/e564973db30a4612aba60c5b26dd108edc98f048/test2sof.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url).drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)

fig = px.treemap(df, path=['type','name'], 
                 values = 'coincidencia',
                 width=900, height=900,
)

# Now your hovertemplate looks like
# fig.data[0].hovertemplate 
# 'labels=%{label}<br>coincidencia=%{value}<br>parent=%{parent}<br>id=%{id}<extra></extra>'

# But it seems to me you want something like
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = '%{label}<br>%{value}'
fig.show()
```